# Adding global attributes such as color/fonts

Tags: css

I am looking for the most practical and convenient way of laying out my site between two CSS files.

One will be for general formatting and the other will include all of the colors and fonts.

Is there a way that I could simply do in the layout file:

```
#sel1 .class1{
color: @color maincolor
}

#sel2 .class2{
color: @color secondarycolor
}
```

and then in my second file simply have the main and secondary colors defined? I know that I could just add `maincolor` and `secondarycolor` as a class to each element, but I don't want to do this to the main document for my own sanity.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should be using a CSS preprocessor such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/). The `@color` variable syntax you suggest in the question is pretty much identical to LESS'.